# How to assign HTML content to iframe control from asp.net codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to assign the html content to iframe control from asp.net code behind page;

this is working fine
myIframe.Attributes.Add("src", "pathtofilewith.html");
but, i don't want to give the path of html file to display i just want to assign some html content which comes from database to iframe control.

i want some thing like this(Ashok) to be displayed in iframe control

i tried the bellow ways but nothing is succesful

```
myIframe.Attributes["innerHTML"] = "<h1>Thank You..</h1>";

myIframe.Attributes.Add("innerHTML", "<h1>Ashok</h1>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. That's not how an `IFRAME` works - it is for use with the src attribute as you've already discovered.

Perhaps you want to create a `DIV` instead

Comment: This accepted answer is no longer correct. You can make an iframe show HTML by setting its `srcdoc` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc You can also set the `src` attribute to a data url containing the encoded HTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs

Answer (score 1):

A way to communicate between two different pages where one is in an IFrame on the other, is to post data using JQuery. An example is given in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003973/target-an-iframe-with-a-html-post-with-jquery)

It is also discussed in [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597548/form-post-in-iframe-without-affecting-history)

On [this page](http://humandoing.net/blog/2011/07/19/set-the-contents-of-an-iframe-using-jquery/), you will also find a short and simple example of how you can put content in an IFrame without using a separate web-page for it (note the lacking `src` attribute!).

Hope some of this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to insert HTML content into **iframe** tag directly, but you can create a page which gets the content form the database and then you can view it using **iframe**,

**or**

You can create a page for example called getContent.aspx which request value from the URL e.g. getContent.aspx?content=`<h1>Thank You..</h1>` and display it wherever you like, and then call it from **iframe**.

Comment: If you want to send the content to another page in such a way though (and I'm not necessarily saying I would! ;) ), it would probably be better to use `Post` instead of a `Get` parameter for two reasons: You can Post more data than you can include with `Get`, and you will also make that data less visible to the client (ie. avoid "cluttering up" the URL of the page if someone should look at the source, or navigate directly to the inner page).