# JQuery post to iframe callback

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, callback

I'm using a form on a page to post data to an iFrame (this can happen as many times as the user requests) As demonstrated here:

[Target an iframe with a HTML Post with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003973/target-an-iframe-with-a-html-post-with-jquery)

I want to be able to perform certain actions in the parent page (resizing the iframe, displaying it if it was previously hidden etc.) when the response has been received and the iframe populated. Is there any way to do this?

I only want to do this whenever a page has been loaded to the iframe and not when the parent page first loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the following javascript to the iframe as well.

```
$('#theId', window.parent.document).html();
```

From there you control the parent and all its components.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, I see that it should though.

Comment: Sorry was being a numpty, I was accidentally adding two jQuery references in the child page! Now this is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a callback useing ("#frameID").load(), that seems to have worked.