# jQuery $.post method, to download file

Tags: jquery, post

I am trying to create download link using jQuery post() method as following:

```
$.post('file.php', {name:'name', id:'id'},
function(data){
    $('#downloadFrame').src = data.url;
});
return true;
```

but always data.url returns null/unidentified, also creating a form and submitting it might be applicable in my code.
I have searched many posts on the forum but none of them works.

thank you.

Comment: What does `file.php` return?

Comment: it should return binary data, according to the input (pdf, xml, ...).
also when I try to alert 'data', it did shows the file bytes.

Comment: In that case, using JQuery's `.post()` method probably won't work. For a start, the frame won't see the `Content-Type` header and so can't work out how the returned data should be displayed.

The method you mention about using a form to submit the request is probably a better way to go. This method is discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1003973/981208).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the zero element of array data, so use `data[0].url`

Change

```
function(data){
    $('#downloadFrame').src = data.url;
});
```

To

```
function(data){
    $('#downloadFrame').src = data[0].url;
});
```

Comment: well, data[0], return the first byte of the php file output, and still url returns null.